# CMFCButton.SetToolTip() crash

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, mfc, tooltip

I'm trying to display a tooltip on a CMfcButton.
When my code run the SetToolTip(), the application crash.

```
BOOL CGenerationDlg::OnInitDialog()
{

    BOOL bret = CPropertyPage::OnInitDialog();

    m_pButtonExport = (CMFCButton *)GetDlgItem(IDC_BTN_EXPORTE_BILAN);
    m_pButtonExport->EnableFullTextTooltip();
    m_pButtonExport->SetTooltip(L"my tooltip");
    return bret;
}


void CKenoDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CPropertyPage::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}
```

Here is my Header file :

```
// KenoDlg.h : fichier d'en-tête
//

#pragma once
#include "keno.h"
#include "AboutDlg.h"

// boîte de dialogue CKenoDlg
class CKenoDlg : public CPropertyPage
{
// Construction
public:
    CKenoDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL); // constructeur standard

    CAboutDlg* myDialog;
// Données de boîte de dialogue
    enum { IDD = IDD_KENO_DIALOG };

    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // Prise en charge de DDX/DDV
    CMFCButton * m_pButtonExport;


// Implémentation
protected:
    HICON m_hIcon;

    // Fonctions générées de la table des messages
    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
    afx_msg void OnPaint();
    afx_msg HCURSOR OnQueryDragIcon();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

public:
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedBtnGenerate();
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedBtnExport();

    afx_msg void OnStnClickedStaticAbout();
    afx_msg HBRUSH OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor);
};
```

Here is my error :

[image]

Any idea please ?

Thanks a lot :)

Best regards,

Comment: That error code (0xC000041D) is identified as a _STATUS_FATAL_USER_CALLBACK_EXCEPTION_.  Can you duplicate the steps to recreate the unhandled exception?

Comment: Duplicate the steps ? i don't understand sorry ! the error is on the SetToolTip() call.

Comment: When you added the button in the resource editor, did you add it as a `CMFCButton` or as a `CButton`? If the latter, you have probably missed the subclassing step that's normally done in the DDX macros.

Comment: Hello, i added it as a CBUtton and modify this as CMCbutton in the header file. Where modifyng the DDX macros please ?

Comment: Can you show your `DoDataExchange` function? This is where you associate a dialog control with a member variable and that's where the subclassing will happen - I just want to see if this is all correct. Also show your header, where you define the member variable.

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni If you can consistently run the application such that it always crashes, you are able to "duplicate the steps" to recreate the crash.  If that is the case, you can run Microsoft's [Application Verifier](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20028) to help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Probleme solved. I modify my CMCbutton variable ( CMFCButton * to CMFCButton ) and added the DDX Function. All is ok now! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Change your header to define a `CMFCButton` instance rather than a pointer:

```
class CKenoDlg : public CPropertyPage
{
    // ... existing code ...

protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // Prise en charge de DDX/DDV
    CMFCButton m_pButtonExport;

    // ... existing code ...
};
```

Then change your `DoDataExchange` function as follows:

```
void CKenoDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CPropertyPage::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_BTN_EXPORTE_BILAN, m_pButtonExport);
}
```

Finally, in `OnInitDialog`, do something like this:

```
BOOL CGenerationDlg::OnInitDialog()
{

    BOOL bret = CPropertyPage::OnInitDialog();

    m_pButtonExport.EnableFullTextTooltip();
    m_pButtonExport.SetTooltip(L"my tooltip");
    return bret;
}
```

The reason why you need to do it like this rather than with a pointer is because MFC has to subclass the control to a `CMFCButton` rather than the default `CButton`. When you use the `DDX` macro in `DoDataExchange`, this is done behind the scenes when the default implementation of `OnInitDialog` calls `UpdateData`, which in turn calls `DoDataExchange` and - if I recall correctly - on the first time through, the dialog controls are sub-classed to the correct types.

As you used a pointer, and had no link between the button control and the type you were using it as, there was a mismatch between the actual and expected types and that was the reason for the crash.

If you use the VS2012 wizard to add a variable from the dialog designer (right-click on a dialog control and choose Add Variable), it will create the member variable declaration in the header file and will add the `DDX` macro to the `DoDataExchange` function for you. You can then choose to change the type of the member variable, e.g. from `CButton` to one of your own `CButton` derived classes.

Comment: It's the solution ! It's perfect ! Thanks ! Nevertheless, could you explain me why it's not ok with the pointer please ?

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni ok, explanation added above - this is *my* understanding of how the MFC framework handles it, you could debug and step into the MFC source code and see this happening to get a better idea. For now, I'm just please you're up and running again :-)

Answer (score 0):

You use the term pointer to button and name the variable 'm_pButtonExport'. That is incorrect. The code creates an instance of a CMFCButton object, not a pointer to an instance of a button object. The variable should be named 'm_ButtonExport' and referred to as an instance of a CMFCButton object NOT a pointer to one.